# Complexity of Perl?

Tags: perl, decomposition

What is the general discussion of the complexity of the [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) programming language, like what should one really focus on when discussing its complexity?

Comment: Complexity... how? It's no more or less complex than any other language for normal use. Granted, it's pretty easy to make a Perl program that looks like it was supposed to be a binary file too, but still, that's **poorly writen** (IMO) code, not the fault of the language.

Comment: I understand the question, but not what they want. You need to tell us what sort of complexity you are asking about...

Comment: You might want to make this a community wiki question, since there's no "answer" that can be accepted.  It's a discussion question.

Answer (score 2):

- Many ways to accomplish the same thing, some of which are poorly structured due to its heritage as a scripting language
- The way that variable references seem to change the type of the variable when you change the leading character, e.g. from @ to $
- The function calling and result returning mechanism
- It is difficult to read PERL. Even the writer of a PERL program will experience difficulty in returning to their own code and making sense of it
- Regular Expressions are too easy to use and often used where a parser or just plain string functions would be clearer and more efficient
- Due to a flood of PERL programming books in the early days of the web, many of which are poorly written, a lot of people learned PERL in a very unstructured way. This makes it harder to manage a team of people writing professional grade code in a consistent way

Answer (score 0):

One source perl's "complexity" comes from there being several ways to do something.

Consider the lowly "if" statement.  Perl offers several alternative if, and if-like constructs.  N00b perl programmers are forced to ask which is "preferred" and find that the answer is often nuanced.

Sometimes it's `do_something || die`, sometimes it's `do_something or die`, sometimes it's a for-real if-statement.